# How does the && work in a foldleft scala

Tags: scala

So i'm reading the "Functional Programing in Scala" and I'm doing exercise 2.2

*Implement isSorted, which checks whether an Array[A] is sorted according to a given comparison function: 
def isSorted[A] (as: Array[A], ordered: (A,A) => Boolean) : Boolean = {*

My solution, which works

```
{
  def orderByValue(a : Int, b : Int): Boolean ={
    println (a + " " + b )
    if( a<= b) true
    else false
  }

  //exercise, def to check wheter an Array[a] is sorted
  def isSorted[A] (as: Array[A], ordered: (A,A) => Boolean) : Boolean = {
    var result = true;
    def loop(n: Int) {
      if (result == false)
        false //Return false on first instance
      else if (n < as.length -1) {
        result = ordered(as(n), as(n + 1))
        loop(n + 1)
      }
      else
        result
    }
    loop(0)
    result
  }
}
```

Was pretty proud of my first go, but thought it doesn't look very functional, so I asked a friend and he came back with

```
{
  def isSorted2[A] (as: Array[A], ordered: (A,A) => Boolean) : Boolean = {
    as.sliding(2,1).foldLeft(true)((res, a ) => ordered(a(0), a(1)) && res)
  }
}
```

Like wtf, how this black magic possible. I understand everything from as.sliding(2,1).foldLeft(true)((res, a ) => ordered(a(0), a(1)), but the && respart, I can't see to find any documentation on it. I know it folds the result of the previous operation, but how does it work, what's this operation called.

Comment: `&&` is the logical AND operator. It's combining the previous result with the next value in the sequence, e.g. `true && false`

Comment: Nothing specific about `foldLeft` there

Comment: This implementation with `foldLeft` looks greedy. I think it always does _(n - 1)_ comparisons even if the very first two elements are not ordered. We can use `forall` like: `as.sliding(2).forall(a => ordered(a(0), a(1)))` which stops immediately if the predicate became `false` for a given pair.

Answer (score 3):

```
def isSorted2[A] (as: Array[A], ordered: (A,A) => Boolean) : Boolean = {
    as.sliding(2,1).foldLeft(true)((res, a ) => ordered(a(0), a(1)) && res)
  }
```

`&&` is a normal logical operator here. The signature of ordered function is  `(A,A) => Boolean` which means it takes two parameters of type A and true a Boolean indicating if argument 1 is greater or smaller than argument2. res is accumulator for the foldLeft function which is set to false even if one of the item is not in proper sort order. This is ensured by the second curried parameter 
`(res, a ) => ordered(a(0), a(1)) && res`

so the simple logic here is that, if the current adjacent items in the list is sorted and all the previous items in the list is also sorted then the list is sorted till the current position. so if we move this current position to the end of the list and if the list is still sorted then the entire list is sorted. But even if one item is not in sorted order compared to its adjacent neighbour than the acc is set to false and the output of the overall method will be false.

The API definition of the foldLeft method is available [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce@foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B)

Comment: One of the difficulty i'm having is;  it looks like ordered takes in 2 variable, a a(0) and another of a(1) + boolean) which it doesn't. How does scala know that this is a result amalgamation?

Comment: @PeterLai ordered(a(0), a(1)) returns a boolean, This boolean is then anded with res, another boolean.  The result of that expression is the return of the function and becomes the res of the next iteration.

Comment: ordered is just a first order function that takes two parameters of type A (the type of the list to be checked) and the returns a boolean. The contract here is that this function should check the value of the parameters passed and must return the appropriate boolean flag to indicate if the two values are smaller or greater than each other..